# Makefile not working when changing function argument to const

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, ld

I have a strange problem when compiling a C++ code using a makefile. The code first compiles perfectly. Then I change one function argument to "const". If I then compile, I will receive the error message when the code tries to use the function in which I changed the argument to const. This can be resolved by removing all .o files and then compiling again, but I am curious as to what causes this issue in the first place. My files are:

**MyClass.h**

```
class MyClass {
public:
void fun(double*const c);
};
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
#include "MyClass.h"
void MyClass::fun(double *const c){
};
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "MyClass.h"
int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    MyClass foo;
    double *bar=new double[2];
    foo.fun(bar);
};
```

**Makefile**

```
all: main

main: Main.o MyClass.o 
    g++ -o a.out Main.o MyClass.o


Main.o: Main.cpp
    g++ -c Main.cpp


MyClass.o: MyClass.cpp
    g++ -c MyClass.cpp
```

If I now first run `make`, everything works. But then I change the signature of `fun` to `fun(const double *const c)`, I receive the error message

```
Main.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `MyClass::fun(double*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

However, if I remove all the .o files and then run `make` again, it compiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule

```
main.o: Main.cpp
```

says thay the `main.o` object file only depend on the `Main.cpp` source file. ***But*** it actually depends on another file: The `MyClass.h` header file.

There's also an error in the capitalization of the name of the target.

The above two problems means that when you change the header file `MyClass.h` to update the function signature, the `Main.o` object file will not be recreated and still reference the old function.

So the rule should be

```
Main.o: Main.cpp MyClass.h
```

That addition will cause the `Main.o` object file to be recompiled when you change the header file.

This change should also be done for the `MyClass.o` target.

---

Also note that the `main` target uses `MyClass.o` as a dependency, but then you use the `MyClass.cpp` *source* file when linking, instead of the object file.

The name of the target should also be the name of the generated file (i.e. `a.out` in your case).

Comment: Thank you, the main.o vs Main.o and MyClass.cpp were typos though, sorry about that. Including MyClass.h as a dependency however indeed solves the problem! But a question then, why is it enough to add MyClass.h as a dependency for Main.cpp, and not also MyClass.cpp?

Comment: @JonathanLindgren Because `make` already recognizes that you changed `MyClass.cpp` and it needs to be recompiled.

Comment: Suggest using `-MD` or similar gcc switch to autogenerate these dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your Makefile is broken: It ignores the fact that a `.o` file does not only depend on the corresponding `.cpp` file, but also on the `.h` files it includes. A correct Makefile rule must include *all* dependencies, including the directly, or even indirectly included `.h` files.

Since you Makefile is incomplete, `make` did not recompile the calling site of your function when its definition changed, so the stale object still references the non-const function. Due to C++ name-mangling, the linker caught it in the act, the error would have gone unnoticed in C!

To fix this situation for good, I recommend spending an hour or two reading this [article on automatic dependency generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/), and implementing some of the solutions it offers into your Makefile. Once you have done this, you will likely just copy-cat your existing solution into the Makefiles of future projects, and otherwise forget about the problem.